# Stored procedure call fails when called from asp.net web app but works when called from SSMS

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

### Background:

We recently had a project where we had to plot Institutions on a Google map however using the address to pinpoint the institution took way to long to load. Therefore we decided to store the lat/lng in the database against the institution record. To get this we created a Stored Procedure `usp_web_kam_Geocode` that calls the GoogleMaps geocoding service to return the coordinates which are then stored.

We then created a trigger `trg_Geocode` on `tblInstitution` after `INSERT, UPDATE` which providing some conditions were met (`bIncludeInKAMMap = 1` i.e. its to be plotted) then it called `usp_web_kam_Geocode` and updates the coordinates on the record.

### Problem:

Once this trigger was added to the table any call to `usp_web_InsertUpdateInstitution` (responsible for inserting and updating `tblInstitution`) **fails without a error** when called from the web app..

We have used SQL Server Profiler to trace this call to `usp_web_InsertUpdateInstitution` which produced the following:

[image]

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=149078313
exec usp_web_InsertUpdateInstitution @lInstitutionID=@p1 output,@lRegionID=132,@TOREFMadisunNumber=N'',@sSageNumber=N'',@sName=N'Replication Test Changed',@Xaddress=N'',@sPostCode=N'GU97DR',@sPhone=N'',@sFax=N'',@lInstitutionTypeID=14,@sNote=N'',@lModifiedByID=0,@sAddress1=N'',@sAddress2=N'',@sAddress3=N'',@sTown=N'',@sCounty=N'',@TOREFCountry=N'',@sWebsite=N'',@lDistributorID=2,@XFCRef=0,@sSICCode=N'',@lEmployees=0,@sSource=N'',@bKeyAccount=0,@TOREFProspectType=N'',@sVAddress1=N'',@sVAddress2=N'',@sVAddress3=N'',@sVTown=N'',@sVCounty=N'',@TOREFVCountry=N'',@sVPostcode=N'',@bHasSepticUnit=0,@lBusinessManagerTempID=0,@lProspectTypeID=1,@lGroupID=1,@lCountryID=180,@lVCountryID=-2,@bDeleted=0,@lValueID=NULL,@sGeneralEmail=N'',@lMarketingID=48509669,@sVisitingAddress=N'',@bIsolator=0,@bLAF=0,@bGradeAB=0,@bGradeCD=0,@bUnclassified=0,@bNoProduction=0,@sIsolatorQty=N'',@sLAFQty=N'',@sGradeABArea=N'',@sGradeCDArea=N'',@sUnclassifiedArea=N'',@bIncludeInKAM=1,@fLat=55.378050999999999,@fLong=-3.4359730000000002,@bRespQuality=0,@bRespMicro=0,@bRespPurchasing=0,@bRespValidation=0,@bKindIsolator=0,@bKindRABS=0,@bKindOLA=0,@bKindOLB=0,@bKindOLC=0,@bKindOLD=0,@lNoCleanroomOperatives=0,@sProductsManufactured=N'',@sComments=N'Test wm4',@lValueAlcohol=0,@lValueBiocides=0,@lValueWipes=0,@lValueEquipment=0,@lValueNonSterile=0,@lValueOther=0,@lGeocodeAttempts=6,@sGeocodeLastStatus=N'OK'
select @p1
```

The first two rows of the screenshot are from the web app (which doesn't work) and the last two are from SSMS (which work correctly)

**BUT** if we copy the exact SQL from above and run it in SSMS (with the same login as the web app) it works correctly inserting or updating a record and successfully retrieves the lat/lng from the webservice

### Code:

#### Institution.Save()

```
Public Function Save() As Integer

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ShieldCRMConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String = "usp_web_InsertUpdateInstitution"

    Try
    cn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim prmInstitutionID As New SqlParameter
    prmInstitutionID.ParameterName = "@lInstitutionID"
    prmInstitutionID.Value = intInstitutionID
    prmInstitutionID.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
    cmd.Parameters.Add(prmInstitutionID)

    '** Parameters clipped out for readability

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Return cmd.Parameters("@lInstitutionID").Value

Catch ex As Exception
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext.Raise(ex)
    Return -1
Finally
    cmd.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
    cn.Dispose()
End Try
```

#### trg_Geolocation

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Geolocation] ON [dbo].[tblInstitution] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @lInstitutionID INT
    DECLARE @sAddress1 VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sAddress2 VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sAddress3 VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sTown VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sCounty VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sPostcode VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @sCountry VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @lCountryID INT

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR

    SELECT lInstitutionID,
           sAddress1,
           sAddress2,
           sAddress3,
           sTown,
           sCounty,
           sPostCode,
           C.lCountryID,
           C.sName AS sCountry
    FROM inserted I
    INNER JOIN refCountry C ON I.lCountryID = C.lCountryID
    WHERE ISNULL(bIncludeInKAM, 0) = 1

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @lInstitutionID, @sAddress1, @sAddress2, @sAddress3, @sTown, @sCounty, @sPostCode, @lCountryID, @sCountry

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @fLat FLOAT
        DECLARE @fLng FLOAT
        DECLARE @sAddress VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @sLastStatus VARCHAR(200)

        SELECT @fLat = NULL, @fLng = NULL, @sAddress = NULL

        SELECT @sAddress =
        CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(@sAddress1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress2 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress3 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sTown + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sCounty + ', ', '') + @sCountry, ', , , ', ', '), ', , ', ', ')
        LIKE ', %' THEN RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(@sAddress1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress2 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress3 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sTown + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sCounty + ', ', '') + @sCountry, ', , , ', ', '), ', , ', ', '),
        LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(@sAddress1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress2 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress3 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sTown + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sCounty + ', ', '') + @sCountry, ', , , ', ', '), ', , ', ', ')) - 2)
        ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(@sAddress1 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress2 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sAddress3 + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sTown + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@sCounty + ', ', '') + @sCountry, ', , , ', ', '), ', , ', ', ') END

        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC usp_web_kam_Geocode @sAddress = @sAddress OUTPUT, @fLat = @fLat OUTPUT, @fLng = @fLng OUTPUT, @sGeocodeLastStatus = @sLastStatus OUTPUT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH    

        IF NOT (@fLat IS NULL AND @fLng IS NULL)
        BEGIN

            UPDATE tblInstitution
            SET fLat = @fLat,
               fLong = @fLng,
               lGeocodeAttempts = ISNULL(lGeocodeAttempts, 0) + 1,
               sGeocodeLastStatus = @sLastStatus
            WHERE lInstitutionID = @lInstitutionID

        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @lInstitutionID, @sAddress1, @sAddress2, @sAddress3, @sTown, @sCounty, @sPostCode, @lCountryID, @sCountry

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

#### usp_web_kam_Geocode

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_web_kam_Geocode]

    @sAddress VARCHAR(80) = NULL OUTPUT,

    @sCity VARCHAR(40) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @sState VARCHAR(40) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @sCounty VARCHAR(40) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @sCountry VARCHAR(40) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @sPostCode VARCHAR(20) = NULL OUTPUT,

    @sGeocodeLastStatus VARCHAR(200) = NULL OUTPUT,
    @fLat FLOAT = NULL OUTPUT,
    @fLng FLOAT = NULL OUTPUT,
    @sMapURL VARCHAR(1024) = NULL OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @sURL varchar(MAX)
    SET @sURL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=' +
    CASE WHEN @sAddress IS NOT NULL THEN @sAddress ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @sCity IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @sCity ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @sState IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @sState ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @sPostCode IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @sPostCode ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @sCountry IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @sCountry ELSE '' END
    SET @sURL = REPLACE(@sURL, ' ', '+')

    DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
    DECLARE @XML xml
    DECLARE @Obj int 
    DECLARE @Result int 
    DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

    EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Obj OUT 

    BEGIN TRY
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @sURL, false
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''

    EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', @Response OUT 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    EXEC @Result = sp_OADestroy @Obj

    IF (@ErrorMsg IS NOT NULL) OR (@HTTPStatus <> 200) BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'Error in Geocode: ' + ISNULL(@ErrorMsg, 'HTTP result is: ' + CAST(@HTTPStatus AS varchar(10)))
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg, 16, 1, @HTTPStatus)
    RETURN 
    END

    SET @XML = CAST(@Response AS XML)

    SET @sGeocodeLastStatus = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/status) [1]', 'varchar(200)') 
    SET @fLat = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat) [1]', 'numeric(9,6)')
    SET @fLng = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng) [1]', 'numeric(9,6)')

    SET @sCity = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="locality"]/long_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)') 
    SET @sState = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="administrative_area_level_1"]/short_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)') 
    SET @sPostCode = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="postal_code"]/long_name) [1]', 'varchar(20)') 
    SET @sCountry = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="country"]/short_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)') 
    SET @sCounty = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="administrative_area_level_2"]/short_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)') 

    SET @sAddress = 
    ISNULL(@XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="street_number"]/long_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)'), '???') + ' ' +
    ISNULL(@XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="route"]/long_name) [1]', 'varchar(40)'), '???') 
    SET @sMapURL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=' + CAST(@fLat AS varchar(20)) + '+' + CAST(@fLng AS varchar(20))

END
```

Comment: I find it usefull to use print statements in a non production environment. Or even write to a XML file for debug purposes. Adding a few of those can point out where your code goes wrong.

It fails: what do you mean? Does the record get updated/inserted?
In your while statement @ trigger maybe you can print or write your error message to a file?

Edit: maybe you need to reconsider your architecture... If you don't need a real-time calculation of the location of your institutions, you could use a scheduled task to update those... Quartz.NET/a simple console program could do the trick?

Comment: My guess would be a permissions error inside `usp_web_kam_Geocode` - Where you call this then catch the error all you do is `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()` - but since you call the original procedure using `ExecuteNonQuery()` this error will never be returned to you.

Comment: Although not related to the actual question, a cursor inside a trigger is generally best avoided, when OLE Automation Stored Procedures are called from within that cursor to call a webservice I think you are asking for performance issues. I would really look at just dumping the rows that need updating into a staging table, then having a background process that does all the updates required. This means that your table is not locked while you are calling external APIs, and also that inserts/updates will not fail because of a problem with GoogleMaps API.

Comment: As @BertPersyn & @GarethD sugested I wrote `ERROR_MESSAGE` to file and got a error about `ARITHABORT` after setting this `ON` it all now works correctly. Thanks everyone!